# Meson operator treated as an elementary field in effective action?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, mesons, 1pi-effective-action

I have seen in many papers, with [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.100) as the earliest example I can find, that the meson chiral order operator $M_j^{\,\,\,i}(x)=\overline{\psi}^i(1+\gamma_5)\psi_j(x)$ is treated as an elementary operator (as opposed to a composite one) when sourcing it to construct an effective potential. The effective potential $V(M)$ is then a general function of $\text{tr}(MM^{\dagger})^n$ for spacetime independent $M$.

Shouldn't this more rigorously be treated as a composite operator $M_j^{\,\,\,i}(x,y)$, and construct the $2$PI effective action according to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.10.2428)? It is my understanding that the effective potential for a composite operator is in general much more complicated than that of an elementary operator, since translation invariance only simplifies the composite operator to depend on $x-y$. This then gives room for complicated spacetime dependent kernels in between each $M_j^{\,\,\,i}(x-y)$.

Under what circumstances are we allowed to treat a composite operator as an elementary field?